# How to correctly exit a for loop and run the next conditional statement

Tags: for-loop, stdstring

UPDATE: Thank you for the help. Writing a demo that you could run did help me solve the issue but not in the way that I expected. I think this is a compiler optimization rather than a bug. When the code inside if ( z == true ) is commented out, the conditional statement is skipped entirely and the control returns to if (x). If I put actual code in, we hit the conditional statement when appropriate.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I have a std::string and I am iterating through it to determine whether it contains certain characters. If any of these characters are found, I want to exit the for loop and proceed with the next conditional statement. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool x = true;
    bool y = true;
    bool z = true;

    std::string str;

    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin >> str;

    if ( x )
    {
        if ( y )
        {
            std::string::iterator i;

            for ( i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); i++ )
            {
                cout << "Enter for" << endl;

                if ( *i == 'a' || *i == 'b' || *i == 'c' )
                {
                    z = false;
                    cout << "Exit for" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( z == true )
            {
                //cout << "z == true" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the program never hits if (z == true). When it breaks out of the loop, control returns to the first conditional statement ( if (x) ).

I tried removing the break and instead setting i = ( str.end() - 1 ). This resulted in the same behavior - it goes back to the for, determines that it's at the last character of the string, and then returns control to the first conditional statement again, skipping the if ( z == true ) as intended.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: your formatting looks messed up  - can you fix it

Comment: assignment != comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"When it breaks out of the loop, control returns to the first conditional statement ( if (something) )."*

When it breaks out of the loop, it has just set `b` to `false`, so the `if (b == true)` code won't run.  What am I misunderstanding?

**Edit**: I think you have oversimplified your code.  Clearly that's not the code you're actually running because `str` never has a value.  You need to post an example that we can actually run (but once you have created such an example, you'll probably find the error for yourself. :-) )

Comment: Some strings will not contain any of those characters, while others will. If the string contains the characters, then set b = false. If the string does not contain any of the characters, then b should be true, and we have other work to do.

Comment: Thanks :) This was a dumb issue.